# Why is the groupRectangle() function attempting to convert a value?

Tags: python, computer-vision, pyautogui

Im using Python, cv2, numpy and pyautogui to bot a simple game it detects apples and stars coming onto the screen it worked fine but got confused when the game sped up as it was only searching for 1 item at a time so I changed to this to detect multiple at a time which works fine however it needs some grouping due to multiple detections of the same object this works sometimes but then after a random amount of time I get the following error...

[Error line 76 cv.groupRectangles() param1 is attempting to convert a value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb1E9.png)

```
while(True):
    scr = np.array(screenshot.grab(dimensions))
    scr_no_alpha = scr[:,:,:3]
    result = cv.matchTemplate(scr_no_alpha, needle, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    result2 = cv.matchTemplate(scr_no_alpha, needle2, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    _, max_val, _, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
    _, max_val2, _, max_loc2 = cv.minMaxLoc(result2)

    src = scr.copy()

    x_top_row, y_top_row = 145,140
    x_middle_row, y_middle_row = 185,185
    x_bottom_row, y_bottom_row = 185,270
    cv.rectangle(src, (x_top_row, y_top_row), (x_top_row+w, y_top_row+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv.rectangle(src, (x_middle_row, y_middle_row), (x_middle_row+w, y_middle_row+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv.rectangle(src, (x_bottom_row, y_bottom_row), (x_bottom_row+w, y_bottom_row+h), (0,255,0), 2)

    x_star_row, y_star_row = 10,120
    cv.rectangle(src, (x_star_row, y_star_row), (x_star_row+w2, y_star_row+h2), (0,255,0), 2)

    threshold = 0.6
    apple_locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
    apple_locations = list(zip(*apple_locations[::-1]))
    threshold = 0.4
    star_locations = np.where(result2 >= threshold)
    star_locations = list(zip(*star_locations[::-1]))

    apple_colour = (0,0,255)
    star_colour = (0,255,255)
    line_type = cv.LINE_4

    if len(apple_locations):
        apples_group = []
        for loc in apple_locations:
            rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), w, h]
            print(rect)
            apples_group.append(rect)
            apples_group.append(rect)
            print(apples_group)
        apples_group, weights = cv.groupRectangles(apples_group, 2, 0.5)

        print(apples_group)
        
        print(f'{len(apples_group)} Needle(s) of type Apple found.')
        
        for (x, y, w, h) in apples_group:
            cv.rectangle(src, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), apple_colour, line_type)
            
            for apple in apples_group:
                if apple[0] in range(x_top_row, y_top_row) and apple[1] in range(x_top_row+w, y_top_row+h):
                    pyautogui.press('w')
                if apple[0] in range(x_middle_row, y_middle_row) and apple[1] in range(x_middle_row+w, y_middle_row+h):
                    pyautogui.press('s')
                if apple[0] in range(x_bottom_row, y_bottom_row) and apple[1] in range(x_bottom_row+w, y_bottom_row+h):
                    pyautogui.press('d')
                
        cv.imshow('Matches', src)
        
    if len(star_locations):
        stars_group = []
        for loc in star_locations:
            rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), w2, h2]
            stars_group.append(rect)
            stars_group.append(rect)
        stars_group, weights = cv.groupRectangles(stars_group, 2, 0.5)
        
        print(f'{len(stars_group)} Needle(s) of type Star found.')
        
        for (x, y, w, h) in stars_group:
            cv.rectangle(src, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), star_colour, line_type)
            
            for star in stars_group:
                if star[0] in range(x_star_row, y_star_row) and star[1] in range(x_star_row+w, y_star_row+h):
                    pyautogui.press('a')
                
        cv.imshow('Matches', src)
    
    cv.waitKey(1)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason the w and h that are entered into the rect list are not always an int value so casting them to an int int(w), int(h) fixes the problem.